# Не выводит изображение Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Не выводит изображение в blade шаблоне. Все остальное отображается корректно.
Ниже код blade:

```
    <div class="carousel-item-a intro-item bg-image" style="background-image: url({{asset('img/slide-1.jpg')}})">
        <div class="overlay overlay-a"></div>
        <div class="intro-content display-table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <div class="intro-body">
                                <p class="intro-title-top">Doral, Florida
                                    <br> 78345</p>
                                <h1 class="intro-title mb-4">
                                    <span class="color-b">204 </span> Mount
                                    <br> Olive Road Two</h1>
                                <p class="intro-subtitle intro-price">
                                    <a href="#"><span class="price-a">rent | $ 12.000</span></a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

папка img находится в public. Все остальное рендерится без проблем. Код страницы выглядит следующим образом

```
<div class="carousel-item-a intro-item bg-image" style="background-image: url(http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/slide-1.jpg)">
            <div class="overlay overlay-a"></div>
            <div class="intro-content display-table">
                <div class="table-cell">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <div class="intro-body">
                                    <p class="intro-title-top">Doral, Florida
                                        <br> 78345</p>
                                    <h1 class="intro-title mb-4">
                                        <span class="color-b">204 </span> Mount
                                        <br> Olive Road Two</h1>
                                    <p class="intro-subtitle intro-price">
                                        <a href="#"><span class="price-a">rent | $ 12.000</span></a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: А просто `url('/img/slide-1.jpg')` не вариант? И у вас там 100% картинка и она открывается по данному пути?

Comment: проверил. картинка открывается по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/slide-1.jpg Может проблема в сервере?(встроен artisan)